# From SurfaceView and Canvas to libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, surfaceview

I initially developed my game on Android Studio using SurfaceView and Canvas, but on getting to completion I realised that my game lags on the android device because it is doing more work than SurfaceView can handle.

My question here is, if it is possible to transfer my game(logic and relevant part of my coding) from SurfaceView to libGDX?

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate your Canvas game with libGDX but that will not profitable because problem is, performance of your game or you can say FPS.

It's better to make your game in libGDX, gameLogic remain same only API changes. Spent some time with libgdx and you will get a Cross Platform game.